# Draw with tikz, as it is shown in the picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

As you start drawing a rectangle on the edge of the page and finish at the other edge with TikZ? As it is shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Search through Se, here is lot of similar questions and answers. Otherwise, this is described in TikZ manual in section 17.13, pp 248.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of application, the `current page` nodes are perfect.

As Zarko proposed in the comments, you can find more information in the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

You can adjust the height of the bar and the y-offset with respect to the center of the page using

```
\setlength\barheight{4cm}
\setlength\yoffset{8cm}
```

Here is the full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newlength\barheight
\newlength\yoffset
\setlength\barheight{4cm}
\setlength\yoffset{8cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
  big text/.style = {
    right=1in+\oddsidemargin,
    font=\Huge\sffamily,
    inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt
  }
  ]
  \filldraw[blue!50] ([yshift=.5*\barheight+\yoffset]current page.west) rectangle ([yshift=-.5*\barheight+\yoffset]current page.east);
  \node[big text] at ([yshift=\yoffset]current page.west) {Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Henri Menke, thank you, and if I wanted to move the rectangle to form vertically at any position on the page , as do that?

Comment: I wonder if can be moved vertically using the form \ node at ( x , y) , and if it can be as serious ? code . Thank you

Comment: I do not mean the vertical size of the rectangle , but to move the position of the rectangle vertically, it can be placed in cualquer bone height of the page

Comment: @casio See updated answer.